Use the same local OneDrive folder for multiple Windows installations
Suppose I have two different Windows installations on one PC that can be booted alternatively.
Can I use a shared partition containing the local OneDrive folder for both Windows installations without corrupting the OneDrive sync state (or something) of either installation?
